# Ruby Sort ActiveRecord - floats stored as strings like floats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Ruby on Rails 4 - Sorting ActiveRecord string column as floats.

I have a RecordModel table with a version column (string) that stores versions. A version is over the format major.minor version. The problem is a version will jump from 9.0 to 10.0, but because it is stored as a string, how do I sort it like an integer?

```
RecordModel(id: integer, version: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

create_table "record_models", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "version"
  t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
end

record_models = RecordModels.all
record_models.order(:version)

# results:
10.10
2.0
3.0
```

Update:
 - Database is postgresql
 - I can't store as a float because some of the version values are blank and some are of the form x.x.x (eg. 1.2.3)

Comment: Try this `record_models.sort_by { |r| r.version.split('.').map(&:to_i) }`........

Comment: if it's just a major/minor why not save it as a float?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Because a version "number" is no more a number than an SSN, zip code, or phone number. They're not numbers at all, they just look sort of like numbers.

Comment: DB is postgresql. I can't store as a float because some of the version values are blank and some are of the format x.x.x

Comment: @muistooshort i was just saying if they are just major.minor then they behave like floats, but then he just said now they also could have a patch, wbeange you should mention in the question that you have patch numbers too.

Comment: @wbeange I've updated my answer to work with postgresql, give it a try and tell me if it works

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this and I don't know how it would behave if the minor is missing, but I think it's worth a try.

```
RecordModel.all.select('*,
  split_part(version, '.', 1)::int as major,
  split_part(version, '.', 2)::int as minor,
  split_part(version, '.', 3)::int as patch'
).order(major: :desc, minor: :desc, patch: :desc)
```

This is updated to work with postgresql

Comment: @muistooshort haven't thought of that, but string i guess, so i guess it still requires a conversion to a number

Comment: @muistooshort i think this should work now, i added int conversion

Answer (score 2):

Since your database is PostgreSQL and this is Rails4, you have full access to PostgreSQL's array columns. That means that you can store a version number like `3.1.4` as the integer array `[3,1,4]`. Note that PostgreSQL arrays compare element by element so sorting on arrays does The Right Thing.

So something like this:

```
create_table "record_models", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "version", array: true
  #...
end
```

for storage should do the trick.

You can still treat them as dot-delimitted strings on input and output by overriding the accessor and mutator methods with something like:

```
def version=(v)
  super(v ? v.split('.').map(&:to_i) : nil)
end
def version
  super.to_a.join('.')
end
```

You'd might want to throw in some extra validations to ensure you're getting the formats you're expecting.

If you want to keep the versions as strings then you could use [`regexp_split_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and a typecast to convert the strings to arrays of integers as needed:

```
...order(%q{regexp_split_to_array(version, '\.')::int[]})
```

Careful with the quoting there, you need to the literal `'\.'` into the database so `%q{...}` is probably the cleanest quoting to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a custom order statement

```
record_models.order('CAST(records.version AS Decimal) DESC')
```

although i'd just recommend storing the version as a float

Comment: maybe something like this? record_models = record_models.reorder("CAST(NULLIF(version, '') AS float) DESC")

Comment: Note that version numbers like 2.1.8 are possible in the updated question and those won't work as floats.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
record_models = record_models.reorder("CAST(NULLIF(version, '') AS float) ASC")
```

Comment: True. I didn't want to get too into the details. I'm pulling versions from an external service and hiding / unhiding records to only display clean major.minor records for now. So I'm getting all records where hidden is false which rules out the patch records for now, which simplifies by problem. I do like @Mohammad's answer which accounts for the patch. Alternatively maybe I could convert the patch and then cast it.